# How to use std::is_same to generate compile time errors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, c-preprocessor

I am using a third party API, which includes a header file that contains a set of typedefs.  Over the past 4 years there have been minor changes to some of the typedefs (e.g. switching between unsigned/signed, changing from int to long etc).

I want to add a compile time check in my code so that I know if a specific typedef has changed.  I was thinking of adding something like the below:

```
#if !std::is_same<::ApiType, int>::value
#error Type has changed
#endif
```

When I tried this out across various typedefs I found that a compile error was always being thrown.

I set up a small console program, which showed the same problem (i.e. always false for preprocessor usage) but was fine outside of the preprocessor:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
#if std::is_same<int, int>::value
  const auto aa = 14; // omitted
#else
  const auto bb = 17;
#endif

#if std::is_same<::DWORD, int>::value
  const auto cc = 14; // omitted
#else
  const auto dd = 17;
#endif

  const auto a = std::is_same<int, int>::value; // true
  const auto b = std::is_same<::DWORD, int>::value; // false
  const auto c = std::is_same<::DWORD, unsigned long>::value; // true

  return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

How do I implement such a compile time check on expected types (specifically to produce a compile time error if the types are not the same)?

Comment: While it isn't like that these days, you should really see the preprocessor and the compiler as two separate entities, almost two different programs that runs separately over the source. The preprocessor first runs over the source and creates the [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) the compiler sees and works on. Therefore the preprocessor has no knowledge of the actual C++ language, including entities like [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) which is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't know anything about types. (Hint: It runs *before* compilation, hence the ‘pre’.)

What you want is [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). E.g:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<::ApiType, int>::value,
              "Type has changed");
```

<sup><sup>Although, since it's an assertion, perhaps it should say ‘has *not*’.</sup></sup>

You can put that almost anywhere, even outside of any function.

Comment: I generally `#define STATIC_ASSERT(e) static_assert( e, #e "// is required" )`. With C++17 there is single-argument `static_assert`. But I think still the more readable message is reason enough to continue using the macro.

Comment: I generally hand-craft a clear and understandable message, perhaps with some good tips on how to resolve whatever went wrong, but to each their own. ;)